# Data modeling - Why not a flat table of attributes?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

I'm working with a colleague new to programming and I'm trying to explain some of the concepts of ORM (and SRP) but I'm somehow failing. This is a Rails app.

The class hierarchy of an application I'm working in goes like this:

-CallFlow
-- Route (polymorphic)
--- RouteOptions

There are attributes specific to the various Routes and each RouteType has it's own set of options. Ideally, to me, there would be a table for call_flows, a table for each of the route types, and then for the route types that have options, an options table for that route type. A really rough mockup:

[image]

Simple_route and outbound_route have no options. Of the routes that do have options, it's a has_many relationship, giving us an array of options for that route.

Conversely, my colleague would like to put all the fields specific to each route on the call_flows table. This is a mockup of that mode:

[image]

So you would have one big call_flows table with fields that don't apply to every record. In fact, only a handful will. My reasoning behind my modeling decision follows:

- It follows the basic normalization patterns
- It reduces the amount of null values, thus db size
- It's more flexible to change
- It follows basic SRP principle

Am I missing anything? It would be nice to have any resources that would help a new programmer  the importance of DB normalization.

Thanks!

Comment: You've explained it very eloquently. If your colleague can't accept your explanation, why would he be convinced by external resources? This looks like a personal leadership/assertiveness issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core concept behind the normalization is `Data Dependency` vs `Functional Dependency`. In a normalized schema, only dependencies are functional dependencies, dictated by the business or the semantics of data. For example, RouteOptions depend on Route.

In a non-normalized table, since all data is stored in all places, there will be data dependencies as well as functional dependencies. In such cases, it is very hard to execute a transaction and assert with 100% confidence that your data model is consistent.

Lets take an example. You want to add a new Route Option. This is your transaction. In a normalized table, you create a new record in RouteOption table and fill the Route_ID in in the same record. You are 100% confident that your data model is consistent after the transaction.

Take a Non-Normalized schema, suppose you have the same RoutOption Table and a RouteSummary Table with columns from several tables in it. When you execute the above transaction on this schema, your data model is not consistent. You have to "remember" to update the RouteSummary Table. After a few days, some other table will be created which will also have RouteOption. The preexisting transactions will not know about this new table.

There is a place for non-normalized schema also. It is, when your data store is not transactional. If it is a ReadOnly schema, largely used for Analytical reasons, there will be no transactions, so there will be no risk of inconsistent data. Hence they are okay in that use case.

Comment: Rearranging between a supertype table design & common+subtypes tables design is not (either of the 2 things referred to as) normalization. And this misuses "data dependency" to mean DB constraint. And a FD is a DB constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you gain by having an the additional *_options tables.  I.e. what goes in here that couldn't just go in the table for the type of route.

That being said,  The sort of complex structure you describe with different route type, options, etc. would seem to be something to me that would lend itself much better to a NoSQL, schema-less storage approach.  IN such a case, you could just have a routes collection each of which can have their own unique structure with regards to properties, options, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear -- each route has_many options tables. So it would be an array of options.

Answer (score 1):

Your case looks like an instance of the design pattern known as “Generalization Specialization” , or Gen-Spec for short.  The question of how to model gen-spec using database tables comes up all the time in SO.

If you were modeling gen-spec in an OOPL such as Java, you would use the subclass inheritance facility to take care of the details for you.  You would simply define a class to take care of the generalized objects, and then define a collection of subclasses with each subclass extending its parent superclass.  It’s easy and straightforward.

Unfortunately the relational data model does not have subclass inheritance built in, and the SQL database systems don’t offer any such facility, to my knowledge. But you’re not out of luck.  You can design your tables to model gen-spec in a way that parallels the class structure of   OOP.   You then have to arrange to implement your own inheritance mechanism when new items are added to the generalized class.   Details follow.

Martin Fowler Identifies three different table designs that mimic inheritance.  The design you favor is close to what Fowler calls [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html).  The design your colleague favors is close to what fowler calls [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html).  Each has its benefits and drawbacks.

The interesting part of Class Table Inheritance is called Shared Primary Key.  Here, the subclass tables have a key that does double duty.  It's a primary key and also a foreign key reference back to the superclass table.  When new entries are made, your application has to propagate the key value from the superclass table to the appropriate subclass table.

The smooth part comes when you need to join the data back together.  Joining based on shared primary keys is slick, easy, and fast.

Comment: What my colleague wants to do is called composition where STI and composition should be used together. Using only composition (call flows have many options) you have a group of polymorphic associations (ivr_route is a call_flow and composed of options) decomposed into one giant class.